# NSString containing aphostrophe (') is not set properly to SOAP service

Tags: objective-c, unicode, nsstring

I have strange in my view problem. I have `UITextField` which contains username. When it contains apostrophe (`'`) the service cannot read username properly. I suppose it is connected with Unicode. I try to see what are the codes and I get:

```
L'TEST - contains code 8217
' - is 39
` - is 96
```

can anyone explains to me why this happens so I can fix this issue

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> L'TEST - contains code 8217

That would be `L’TEST` with `U+2019 ‹’› \N{RIGHT SINGLE QUOTATION MARK}`. If you look closely, in most fonts this character is displayed with a slight curl. It's not an apostrophe, but *misused* as one.

> can anyone explains to me why this happens

Common causes:

- "The Fool" Some mischievous input system silently substituted apostrophe for quotation mark. Word processors and mobile OS on-screen keyboards do that. It's well-meaning, but sometimes produces the wrong result.
- "The Clueless" User is ignorant how to correctly type an apostrophe and picked the similar looking quotation mark.
- "The Angry" Your UI text field (or something else in the chain originating from the user) forbids entry of apostrophes for some retarded reason. The user absolutely refuses to write something orthographically incorrect and manually substitutes apostrophe for quotation mark in order to work around the defect software.

> so I can fix this issue

This is a social problem, not a software problem.

Comment: 10x, @daxim. Great answer with one remark - in my case it is a software probelm, because usernames came from external system (WEB) and they can add simple `'`, so I need to make replace. By the way in iOS keyboard the symbol is `right single quoted mark`, but on Android there is `'` and `.

Answer (score -1):

Since a SOAP service is based on XML and single quotes are a delineator in XML, you need to escape your single quotes by replacing "'" with "\'" in all text fields.  It's a very common issue.

Comment: My problem, @Michael Dougan is when I send data the service receives wrong apostrophe. From my research now I think that the problem is in the objective-c code. I can not even make replace of that symbol inside `NSString`. For example when I decided to replace `'` with `zzz` I got `L'TEST`, but when I try to replace `L` with `zzz` I got `zzz'TEST`.

Comment: I've sometimes had to copy a character directly from the string and paste it into my replace statement to get the right character to be replaced, even though they might look identical.